# How do you test for value in multiple column array using key column and one more column

Tags: php

I am having  multiple column array and want to test existence of an id key

but meeting the gender criteria column as well.

I am trying to achieve this without looping the array.

```
<?php
// An array that represents a possible record set returned from a database
$a = array(

array(
'id' => 5698,
'first_name' => 'Peter',
'gender' => 'Male',
),
array(
'id' => 4767,
'first_name' => 'Ann',
'gender' => 'Female',
),
array(
'id' => 3809,
'first_name' => 'Joe',
'gender' => 'Male',
)
);

?>
```

To test if joe id key exists i am able to

```
<?php
if  (array_key_exists(3809), $a)) {
            echo ("That key WAS found");
            }else{
            echo "That key was NOT found";
            } 
?>
```

My difficulty is i need to test array_key_exists(3809), $a
where gender equals Male.

Is there a way to achieve this without looping the multi column array?
Something like.

```
 if  (array_key_exists(3809) and gender == 'Male' , $a)) {
            echo ("That key WAS found");
            }else{
            echo "That key was NOT found";
            } 
  ?>
```

Anyone with idea kindly share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare the element with the `gender` key normally after testing whether the key exists.

```
if (array_key_exists(3809, $a) && $a[3809]['gender'] == 'Male') {
```